# esp-01 with rf receiver keeps crashing

Tags: esp8266, c++, rf, buzzer

SOLVED:
after may hours of testing i have solved the problem.
it turned out to not be a software issue. the power supply i was using did not have a flyback diode and thus caused large voltage spikes that would crash the esp. the solution was to add a diode on the inductive load to remove those voltage spikes.

I have an esp-01 running some code that checks for a rf remote signal using the rc-switch library, it is also running some blynk and ota code.

when i press one of the buttons on my rf remote the *buzzer* pin keeps being triggered but will not shut off, eventually the esp will crash..

the device is in a permanent location thus the reason for the ota updates and i cant easily hookup a serial monitor to see what the esp crash code is.

the troublesome code is,

```
    void newloop() {
      if (mySwitch.available()) {
        // int recieved = mySwitch.getReceivedValue();
        if (mySwitch.getReceivedValue() == 5099665) {
          digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
          delay(200);
          digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
          mySwitch.resetAvailable();
        }
        else if (mySwitch.getReceivedValue() == 5099666) {
          digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
          delay(2000);
          digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
          mySwitch.resetAvailable();
        }
      }
      // Blynk.run();
    }
```

the full code, with redacted passwords/keys is,

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <ArduinoOTA.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial
#include <RCSwitch.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h>
#define buzzer 2
char auth[] = "<blynk auth>";
RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();

const char* ssid = "HansenHome";
const char* password = "<wifi password>";
ESP8266WebServer server;

bool ready = false;
bool ota_flag = true;
uint16_t time_elapsed = 0;

void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Booting");
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
  Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, password);
  mySwitch.enableReceive(0);

  
  while (WiFi.waitForConnectResult() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("Connection Failed! Rebooting...");
    delay(5000);
    ESP.restart();
  }
  
  // Hostname defaults to esp8266-[ChipID]
  ArduinoOTA.setHostname("lock");

  // No authentication by default
  ArduinoOTA.setPassword("<uploading password>");

  ArduinoOTA.onStart([]() {
    String type;
    if (ArduinoOTA.getCommand() == U_FLASH) {
      type = "sketch";
    } else { // U_SPIFFS
      type = "filesystem";
    }

    // NOTE: if updating SPIFFS this would be the place to unmount SPIFFS using SPIFFS.end()
    Serial.println("Start updating " + type);
  });
  ArduinoOTA.onEnd([]() {
    Serial.println("\nEnd");
  });
  ArduinoOTA.onProgress([](unsigned int progress, unsigned int total) {
    Serial.printf("Progress: %u%%\r", (progress / (total / 100)));
  });
  ArduinoOTA.onError([](ota_error_t error) {
    Serial.printf("Error[%u]: ", error);
    if (error == OTA_AUTH_ERROR) {
      Serial.println("Auth Failed");
    } else if (error == OTA_BEGIN_ERROR) {
      Serial.println("Begin Failed");
    } else if (error == OTA_CONNECT_ERROR) {
      Serial.println("Connect Failed");
    } else if (error == OTA_RECEIVE_ERROR) {
      Serial.println("Receive Failed");
    } else if (error == OTA_END_ERROR) {
      Serial.println("End Failed");
    }
  });
  ArduinoOTA.begin();
  Serial.println("Ready");
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  server.on("/restart",[](){
    server.send(200,"text/plain", "Restarting...");
    delay(1000);
    ESP.restart();
  });

  server.on("/setflag",[](){
    server.send(200,"text/plain", "Setting flag...");
    ota_flag = true;
    time_elapsed = 0;
  });

  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  if(ota_flag)
  {
    uint16_t time_start = millis();
    while(time_elapsed < 10000)
    {
      ArduinoOTA.handle();
      time_elapsed = millis()-time_start;
      delay(10);
    }
    ota_flag = false;
  }
  if(ready == false) {
    ready = true;
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
    delay(20);
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    delay(20);
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
    delay(20);
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    delay(20);
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
    delay(20);
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    delay(20);
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
    delay(20);
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    ready = true;
  }
  server.handleClient();
  newloop();
}


BLYNK_WRITE(V1) {
  digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
}

void newloop() {
  if (mySwitch.available()) {
    // int recieved = mySwitch.getReceivedValue();
    if (mySwitch.getReceivedValue() == 5099665) {
      digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
      mySwitch.resetAvailable();
    }
    else if (mySwitch.getReceivedValue() == 5099666) {
      digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
      delay(2000);
      digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
      mySwitch.resetAvailable();
    }
  }
  // Blynk.run();
}
```

EDIT:

so after so further testing it appears to be a power supply issue, the power supply i was using was hooked up to a large inductive load. once that load is turned off there is a huge power spike and for some reason causing the esp to crash.

the board the esp is on has 2 voltage regulators and a few input caps

i added a large cap to the main supply and a 100uf to the 3.3v rail directly on the esp. it is still crashing..

Comment: try printing a message to serial, instead of buzzer and delay code

Comment: i cant get a proper serial output.. i may be able to move it around and get a monitor hooked up to it but it will take time

Comment: i changed the power supply while testing and it has not broke yet, so it may have to do with that

Comment: I believe you are allowed to post answers to your own questions as weird as that sounds.

Comment: By which I mean via "Post Your Answer" button rather than placing it into the question.  You could, if you wanted, have you edit say "I solved this myself, see my answer below" I suppose.